# Prove that $\sum |x_k| < \infty \iff \sum |x_k|^p < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

I'm trying to solve this problem about series. Could you please verify if my attempt is fine or it contains logical gaps/mistakes? I'm grateful for your help!

> Let $\mathbb K$ denote $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, $(x_k)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb K$, and $1 \le p \in \mathbb R$. Then $$\sum |x_k| < \infty \iff \sum |x_k|^p < \infty$$

**My attempt:**

We define partial sums $s_n,s'_n$ by $$s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n |x_k|, \quad s'_n = \sum_{k=0}^n |x_k|^p$$

> **Lemma:** For all $n \in \mathbb N$, we have $$(s_n)^p \ge s'_n \ge s_n$$

If $\sum |x_k| < \infty$ then there exists $M \ge 0$ such that $s_n \le M$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. By Lemma, $s'_n \le (s_n)^p \le M^p$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. As such, $s'_n$ is bounded from above and thus $\sum |x_k|^p < \infty$.

If $\sum |x_k|^p < \infty$ then there exists $N \ge 0$ such that $s'_n \le N$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. By Lemma, $s_n \le s'_n \le L$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. As such, $s_n$ is bounded from above and thus $\sum |x_k| < \infty$.

Comment: $\sum (\frac{1}{n})^2$ converges but $\sum {\frac{1}{n}}$ does not...

Comment: Don't you mean to prove: $\sum|x_k|<\infty\iff\forall p\in[1,\infty)\;\sum|x_k|^p<\infty$?

Comment: Hi @drhab, I meant to prove that, but it is false as pointed out by other people :)

Comment: No, the statement in my comment is true. But the statement: $$\forall p\in[1,\infty)\;\left[\sum|x_k|<\infty\iff\sum|x_k|^p<\infty\right]$$ is false (as pointed out). The statements are not the same.

Comment: Thank you @drhab, I got it.

Comment: I don't know why this question get downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication is obvious since $|x_k|^p\leq |x_k|$ for all $k$ big enough but the converse is not true as $|x_k|=\frac{1}{k}$ prove.

Answer (score 2):

Your lemma is false. For a correct proof of $\implies$ just note that $|x_k| <1$ for $k$ sufficiently large and $|x| <1$ implies $|x|^{p} \leq |x|$. The reverse implication is false since $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}} <\infty$ but $\sum \frac 1 n =\infty$.